# Xamarin Forms Webview crashes unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.ios

I have a **Xamarin Forms** mobile app that contains a **Webview**. The contents of the **Webview** is dynamically generated HTML. It's actually a questionnaire that we generate for each customer, whereby the questions will be different. This is why we have used a **Webview**, as it allows us to generate dynamic HTML for each customer.

Here's the XAML for the Webview (simplified for clarity).

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- WebView needs to be given height and width request within layouts to render. -->
        <WebView x:Name="WebView" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here's the code in the **Xamarin Form** code that populates the **Webview** (simplified for clarity).

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    WebView.IsVisible = false;

    var questionnaire = await InspectionView.GetVehicleInspection();
    this._vehicleInspection = questionnaire;
    StringBuilder htmlString = new StringBuilder();

    string generatedHtml = new VehicleInspectionServices().GenerateHtmlFromVehicleInspection(questionnaire);
    htmlString.Append(generatedHtml);

    var htmlWebView = new HtmlWebViewSource { Html = htmlString.ToString() };
    WebView.Source = htmlWebView;
    WebView.IsVisible = true;
}
```

Here's a snippet of the resultant HTML that is generated and displayed in the **Webview**.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel=stylesheet href=https://myazurestorage.blob.core.windows.net/myblobname/styles.css\>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <h2>Internal</h2>
                <h3>Is the interior clean?</h3>
                <input id=radio30216 type=radio name=radiobuttons100068 value=30216</input>
                <label for=radio30216>Clean</label><input id=radio30217 type=radio name=radiobuttons100068 value=30217</input>
                <label for=radio30217>Ok</label><input id=radio30218 type=radio name=radiobuttons100068 value=30218</input>
                <label for=radio30218>Unclean</label>

                <hr>
                <h3>Are seat belts working?</h3>
                <input id=radio30219 type=radio name=radiobuttons100069 value=30219</input>
                <label for=radio30219>Yes</label><input id=radio30220 type=radio name=radiobuttons100069 value=30220</input>
                <label for=radio30220>No</label><hr>

                <h3>Are there any warning lights on the dashboard?</h3>
                <input id=radio30221 type=radio name=radiobuttons100070 value=30221</input>
                <label for=radio30221>Yes</label>
                <input id=radio30222 type=radio name=radiobuttons100070 value=30222</input>
                <label for=radio30222>No</label>

                <hr>
                <h3>If yes please provide information</h3>
                <input type=text id=text100071></input>

                <hr>
                <h2>External</h2>
                <h3>Are there and dents or scratches on the bodywork?</h3>
                <input id=radio30232 type=radio name=radiobuttons100075 value=30232</input>
                <label for=radio30232>Yes</label><input id=radio30233 type=radio name=radiobuttons100075 value=30233</input>
                <label for=radio30233>No</label>

            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

It's pretty standard HTML (which was the intention).

On Android devices the **Webview** is rock solid and has never crashed once. On Apple devices however (iPhones / iPads), the app will sometimes suddenly close. Usually as the user scrolls through the **Webview** and fills out the questions. It's very unpredicatable. It works on some devices, but not others. Diagnosing the problem is very difficult.

Has anyone else seen similar behaviour using a **Webview**? Any suggestions as to why it suddenly closes, and only on Apple devices?

**UPDATE**

We have seen the issue on the following devices.

- iPhone 8 running iOS 12.1
- iPhone 8 Plus running iOS 12.1.4
- iPhone 8 running iOS 12.1.4
- iPad Mini 2 running iOS 11.1.2

Here's an example of the error whilst running Visual Studio 2017 15.9.4 (truncated as the actual error was very lengthy)

```
2019-03-01 09:28:07.857 IFMDriverServicesiOS[274:5768] critical: Stacktrace:
2019-03-01 09:28:07.857 IFMDriverServicesiOS[274:5768] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2019-03-01 09:28:07.860 IFMDriverServicesiOS[274:5768] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) SkiaSharp.SkiaApi.sk_canvas_draw_path (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00007>

2019-03-01 09:28:07.877 IFMDriverServicesiOS[274:5768] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
2019-03-01 09:28:07.923 IFMDriverServicesiOS[274:5768] critical:    0   IFMDriverServicesiOS                0x000000010356d564 GMSx_AbslInternalSpinLockWake + 800720
2019-03-01 09:28:07.923 IFMDriverServicesiOS[274:5768] critical:    1   IFMDriverServicesiOS                0x000000010357b234 mono_pmip + 16100
2019-03-01 09:28:07.923 IFMDriverServicesiOS[274:5768] critical:    2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001822cc9f0 <redacted> + 56
2019-03-01 09:28:07.924 IFMDriverServicesiOS[274:5768] critical:    3   libSkiaSharp                        0x00000001043b4bbc gr_glinterface_has_extension + 1348628
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
The app has been terminated.
Failed to Stop app:  An error occured on client IDB412377 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.12.3.77/stop-app
The app has been terminated.
```

Comment: this could potentially be a bug but I have a feeling there might be something missing when the app crashes what exactly is logged in the Output window? is there an exception of some kind thrown?

Comment: We're primarily seeing the problem on test devices, rather than the ones we use for development. That said, we have seen the issue in development. I'll check and see what exception or log output were generated.

Comment: Do that and post it here as text and not an image

Comment: The crash report in my post is text. It references the SkiaSharp library which seems to suggest the issue is related to the handling of the graphics on iOS.

Comment: From what I see this is not all the error and neither is this a webview issue what versions of skiasharp libraries do you have?

Comment: The error was too lengthy to post in its entirety, so I trruncated it for the purposes of brevity. I have included the top and bottom parts of the error which seems reasonable.  I am using Xamarin.Forms v3.2.0.871581. SkiaSharp I am assuming is part of the Xamarin.Forms mono runtime.

Comment: SkiaSharp is a different library if I am not wrong because I do have it in my current project, anyway, can you update XF to latest v3.6 something is the latest stable and check whether this issue persists?

Comment: I've upgraded to Xamarin.Forms 3.5.0.169047 which seems more stable, but it's still crashing. I've managed to submit a couple of inspections, but it's crashed twice too. That's definitely progress and better than it was, but not ready for release either.

Comment: No 3.5 has a lot of bugs go to 3.6 if you ask me!

Comment: I'm assuming 3.6 is only available for VS2019. I'm using VS2017 v15.9.4. It's only giving me the option of upgrading to 3.5.

Comment: Oh I see okay no problem, is it still throwing the same error?

Comment: Yes exactly the same problem :( I'll speak to my manager on Monday about upgrading to VS2019. Thanks for you help and patience I appreciate it :)

Comment: Sure no problem I would suggest you check if you have SKIASharp installed in your application references\

Comment: Will will have a look at that :)

Comment: Sure go ahead let me know if you find anything

Comment: The iOS project contained 3 SkiaSharp nuget packages, which I have now upgraded to v1.68.0. I've submitted 3 inspections so far without a problem. This seems to have resolved the problem :)

Comment: Yes it will lets see what happens do let me know what happens does it still crash!

Comment: It hasn't crashed in development. I'm going to do a build and get our testers to check it over now.

Comment: I am pretty sure it won't crash now as I have just checked in my current app I have the same version of SkiaSharp and we have lots of webviews with no such issues

Comment: That's good to know. And again, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Sure, let me know what happens! If it works or not